# Parsing EMV tag 9F4F (Log Format)

Tags: logging, emv

I am trying to parse EMV tag 9F4F (Log Format). This returns a string:

```
9F 27 01 9F 02 06 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9F 36 02 9F 52 06 DF 3E 01 9F 21 03 9F 7C 14
```

This result consists of Tag+Length, but it is not TLV encoded. I know that the first tag is 9F27 with length 01 (i can see this in cardpeek). But how can i parse/dismantle this string of Tag+Lenght pairs?

In the [EMV 4.3 Book 3](https://www.emvco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/EMV_v4.3_Book_3_Application_Specification_20120607062110791.pdf) - Annex D5, shows an example of such a log format but it doesnt show how to read/parse this result.

> In Table 45, lengths and tags are shown for clarity. They do not
> appear in the log record which is the concatenation of values (no TLV
> coding).

The format of this result is clearly not TLV, but does anyone know what format it is in - if there is any? Or is it just a concatenated string of tag + length values?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Do you not understand the TLV format?  Is there some point in the referenced appendix that confuses you?

Comment: @Kevin i modified the question, i know the format is not TLV as is stated in the EMV Book, but i would like to know if it is another format - if there is any? Im now copying the tags first by 2 bytes and try to find a matching tag, if not found i will copy 4 bytes and try to find a matching tag. This works - but is this "the right way" or am i missing something / not seeing something in the EMV book?

Comment: I'm not sure why you tag the question with asn.1 and ber ...

Comment: @YaFred I removed the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Log Format (9F4F) is a list in tag and length format (i.e., "TL" instead of TLV) See description in Table 33 on page 141.

In your example, "9F 27 01 9F 02 06 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9F 36 02 9F 52 06 DF 3E 01 9F 21 03 9F 7C 14" means:

- 9F27 01 (Cryptogram Information Data)
- 9F02 06 (Amount, Authorised)
- 5F2A 02 (Transaction Currency Code)
- 9A   03 (Transaction Date)
- 9F36 02 (Application Transaction Counter)
- 9F52 06 (Terminal Compatibility Indicator)
- DF3E 01
- 9F21 03 (Transaction Time)
- 9F7C 14 (Visa Customer Exclusive Data)

It's almost identical to the example in D5.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, i got it working.. I first thought it was another form of TLV, but your answer confirmed what i thought.